# MVC dropdownlist, cannot bind the selected value to the dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC project i am trying to bind the selected value in a dropdownlist.
For example, for the AUTHOR_ID field, the textfield is filed with the value and also the dropdownlist, but the selected value isn't set.

I am using the following class (model).

## ProfileCard

```
Public Class ProfileCard
    Public Property SearchIndex As Integer
    <Key()>
    Public Property DOCNUM As String
    Public Property DOCNAME As String
    Public Property TYPIST_ID As String
    Public Property AUTHOR_ID As String
    Public Property TYPE_ID As String
    Public Property LAST_EDIT_ID As String
    Public Property APP_ID As String
    Public Property CREATION_DATE As String
    Public Property LASTEDITDATE As String
    Public Property ABSTRACT As String
    Public Property postedfile As HttpPostedFileBase
    Public Property profileError As String
    'listbox items
    Public Property GetAuthors As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    Public Property GetApplications As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    'list with profile defaults 
    Public Property ListofProfileDefaults As List(Of ProfileDefaults)
End Class

Public Class ProfileDBContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property ProfileCards() As DbSet(Of ProfileCard)
End Class
Public Class ProfileDefaults

    Public Property id As String
    Public Property desc As String
    Public Property type As String

End Class
```

This is the Edit function in the controller

## Edit function

```
Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult

    Dim ds As New ProfileCard

    Dim selectpeople = (From t In db.PEOPLE
    Select New SelectListItem With {.Text = t.USER_ID.ToString, .Value = t.USER_ID.ToString})

    Dim selectapplications = (From t In db.APPS
    Select New SelectListItem With {.Text = t.APPLICATION.ToString, .Value = t.APPLICATION.ToString})

    ds.GetAuthors = selectpeople
    ds.GetApplications = selectapplications

    'list profile defaults!
    ds.ListofProfileDefaults = Session("_lProfileDefaults")

    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In ds.GetType().GetProperties()
        If p.CanRead Then
            If Not UCase((";SearchIndex;postedfile;GetAuthors;GetApplications;ListofProfileDefaults;")).Contains(";" & UCase(p.Name) & ";") Then
                Dim retval As Type = p.PropertyType
                Dim answer As Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(retval)
                Dim value As Object
                If answer Is Nothing Then
                    value = System.Convert.ChangeType("Some value", retval)
                Else
                    value = System.Convert.ChangeType("Some value", answer)
                End If

                p.SetValue(ds, value, Nothing)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Return View(New List(Of ProfileCard)() From {ds})

End Function
```

This is the code in the view.

## View

```
@ModelTYPE IEnumerable(Of DMMvcApplication.ProfileCard)
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@<fieldset>
    
     @For Each item In Model
             Dim listofrProfileDefaults = item.ListofProfileDefaults

             @For Each a In listofrProfileDefaults

                    Select Case UCase(a.id)
                        Case "DOCNUM"
                        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(modelItem) item.DOCNUM)
                    Case "DOCNAME"
                        @Html.Label(a.desc)
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(modelitem) item.DOCNAME)

                    Case "AUTHOR_ID"
                        @Html.Label(a.desc)
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(modelitem) item.AUTHOR_ID)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(modelitem) item.AUTHOR_ID, item.GetAuthors, New With {.class = "chosenDropDown"})

                    Case "CREATION_DATE"
                        @Html.Label(a.desc)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(modelitem) item.CREATION_DATE, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", New With {.class = "datecss"})

                    Case "APP_ID"
                        @Html.Label(a.desc)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(modelitem) item.APP_ID, item.GetApplications, New With {.class = "chosenDropDown"})
                
                    End Select
                
            Next

        @<p> 

        </p>

     Next

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Αλλαγή" />
</p>
</fieldset>
@<div id="dialog_lookup" style="display: none">
</div>
End Using
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Επιστροφή", "Index", "SearchResults")
</div>
```

Thanks,
Thanasis.

## Update

I think i solved it like this:

I had:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(modelitem) item.AUTHOR_ID, item.GetAuthors, New With {.class = "chosenDropDown"})
```

And i changed it to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(modelitem) item.AUTHOR_ID, New SelectList(item.GetAuthors, "Value", "Text", item.AUTHOR_ID), New With {.class = "chosenDropDown"})
```

The key was the new SelectList with the Value and Text attributes.

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076600/dropdownlistfor-mvc-asp-net-vb what is in the function needs to match what is outside.  so it should be modelItem.DOCNUM instead of item.DOCNUM

Comment: I get this error
'DOCNUM is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of DMMvcApplication.ProfileCard)'
You think i should focus and solve this?

Comment: sounds like it is getting confused.  for simplicity try changing all of the modelItems to just x or something different from your model.  see if that helps